# Php cURL error:error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Tags: php, ssl, curl

**I already searched stackoverflow as well as other sources unfortunately i got no perfect solution to solve this issue even i tried every way so my request is help in code not share any links **

i am using ZeroXIII - 13.3.2 on windows 7 here is my php Curl function for download web pages

```
function gdllssl3($target_url) {
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$target_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FAILONERROR, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, "D:\cacert-2019-05-15.pem");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION,4);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,10);
$html= curl_exec($ch);
if (!$html) {
        echo "<br />cURL error number:" .curl_errno($ch);
        echo "<br />cURL error:" . curl_error($ch);
}
return $html;
}


echo $url=gdllssl3('https://www.ratemyagent.com.au/real-estate-profile/sales/new-south-wales/agents');
```

it return me this error

*cURL error number:35
cURL error:error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure*

using latest CA certificates extracted from Mozilla

Comment: ServerHello TLS message happens before any certificate exchanges, so the problem can not be related to whatever certificate or CA you use.

Comment: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);` this is **VERY BAD** and **SHOULD NOT** be done. You open yourself to hijacking attacks, and basically this voids any usefulness of doing HTTPS (TLS), you might as well do HTTP.

Comment: Generic comment: saying "I already searched... i got no perfect solution ... even I tried every way" is absolutely not useful (and you could edit your question to remove that as it does not add anything). Noone can know which solutions you found and exactly what you did test. You should instead clearly spell out what you have tried, what results you got, and what you expected instead. A "notice" like you did will not prevent people judging your question is a duplicate to any other asking for this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you are trying to connect to a remote server supporting TLS v1.1 and TLS v1.2, not TLS v1.0

Could you try to change this line:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 4);
```

to

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_1);
```

CURLOPT_SSLVERSION `4` (CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_0) means TLS v1.0, while `5` (CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_1) means TLS v1.1

For information, TLS v1.0 is now deprecated and must be avoided for security reasons.
https://blog.pcisecuritystandards.org/are-you-ready-for-30-june-2018-sayin-goodbye-to-ssl-early-tls

Eventually, as mentioned by Patrick Mevzek in the comments below, you'd better remove that line completely to let the curl module choose the best supported protocol, as stated in the documentation ([PHP cURL](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.curl-setopt.php))

Comment: You shouldn't force a specific version. What if the server supports 1.2 (far better than 1.1)? You could have autonegotiated that, instead of forcing 1.1 And even more so when the server stops accepting 1.1 your code stops working... Except in very specific conditions, prefer autonegotiation, the library will auto select the best (highest version). See documentation, which says "Your best bet is to not set this and let it use the default.".

Comment: But, indeed, using symbolic constants is far better than integers. Who will remember that `4` stands for `TLS 1.0` in curl?

Comment: I totally agree with you, still its a way for the OP to understand the meaning of this curl option (and maybe the meaning of other of options used, like using VERIFYPEER `false` while using CAINFO...)

Comment: You could still give him a better advice on just removing that line completely...

Comment: And indeed, based on https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=www.ratemyagent.com.au&s=99.84.224.71 the server is capable of negotiating either 1.1 or 1.2, so it is better to use the greatest one, that is 1.2 and not forcing a downgrade to 1.1. There may be problems however for the OP, as he mentions using Windows 7. Based on https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/clients.html some clients can not do 1.2 on Windows 7. This OS version is EOL in 6 months (January 2020) cf https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/13853/windows-lifecycle-fact-sheet

Comment: Indeed, thank you, I have added this preferred option to the answer.